# How to insert a list inside php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I know this is a dumb question but I don't know anything about php and I want to insert a list in php to use it late as a shortcode. Here is the code that I have problem with in functions.php

```
function optionalone_function() {
echo " <ul>
<li>5 pages Web</li>
<li><i class="icon-circle-check"></i> one</li>
<li><i class="icon-circle-check"></i> two</li>
<li><i class="icon-circle-check"></i> three</li>
<li><i class="icon-circle-check"></i> four</li>
<li><i class="icon-circle-check"></i> five</li>
<li><i class="icon-circle-Check"></i>six</li>
<li><i class="icon-circle-check"></i> seven</li>
</ul>\n";
}
add_shortcode( 'optionalone', 'optionalone_function' );
```

Comment: you didn't tell us what the problem is or if you're getting errors.

Comment: the code coloring on the string already tells the story

Comment: @Ghost I saw that also but couldn't put my finger on it. You talking about the letter case? If so, they would have gotten an error about it, right?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in (root-file)functions.php on line 7

Comment: @Ghost Duh........ I got it now lol. the quotes. (facepalm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the double quotes in the class part to the single quotes. PHP is getting confused. Do like this:

```
function optionalone_function() {
echo " <ul>
<li>5 pages Web</li>
<li><i class='icon-circle-check'></i> one</li>
<li><i class='icon-circle-check'></i> two</li>
<li><i class='icon-circle-check'></i> three</li>
<li><i class='icon-circle-check'></i> four</li>
<li><i class='icon-circle-check'></i> five</li>
<li><i class='icon-circle-Check'></i>six</li>
<li><i class='icon-circle-check'></i> seven</li>
</ul>\n";
}
add_shortcode( 'optionalone', 'optionalone_function' );
```

Inside the double quotes (example: "this is inside"), you need to put the single quotes. If you put the double quotes inside, that means you have finished entering the string, double quotes have ended, and you are confusing the PHP. Do like I wrote to you, instead. If everything else you wrote is correct, you should be good.

Comment: Thank you it worked